# Finding the MSE of a uniformly distributed random variable

Tags: statistics

Below is a problem I did from the book "Mathematical Statistics with Applications". It is problem 8.6. For parts a and b, I believe I did the correctly since my answer match's the answer in the back of the book. However, it does not for part c. I would like to know what I did wrong.

Problem:
The reading on a voltage meter connected to a test circuit is uniformly distributed over the interval $(\theta,\theta+1)$ where $\theta$ is the true but unknown voltage of the circuit. Suppose that $Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_n$ denotes the a random sample of such readings.
(a) Show that $\overline{Y}$ is a biased estimator of $\theta$ and compute the bias.
(b) Find a function of $\overline{Y}$ that is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$.
(c) Find $MSE(\overline{Y})$ when $\overline{Y}$ is used as estimator of $\theta$.

Answer:(a)
Since each reading is going to be above the actual reading, $\overline{Y}$ must be above the actual mean. Let $B$ be the bias we seek.
\begin{align*}
B &= E(\overline{Y}) - Y \\
E(\overline{Y}) &= \int_{\theta}^{\theta+1} y \, dy = \frac{y^2}{2} \Big|_{\theta}^{\theta+1} \\
E(\overline{Y}) &= \frac{(\theta+1)^2}{2} - \frac{\theta^2}{2} = \frac{\theta^2 + 2\theta + 1}{2} - \frac{\theta^2}{2} \\
E(\overline{Y}) &= \frac{2\theta + 1}{2} \\
B &= \frac{2\theta + 1}{2} - \theta \\
B &= \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
Part b:
Let $u$ be the unbiased estimator we seek:
$$ u = \overline{Y} - \frac{1}{2} $$
Part c:
\begin{align*}
MSE(\overline{Y}) &= V(\overline{Y}) + B^2 \\
\text{Now we need to find the variance of $\overline{Y}$.} \\
MSE(\overline{Y}) &= E((\overline{Y} - Y)^2) \\
E((\overline{Y} - Y)^2) &= \int_{\theta}^{\theta+1} \left( \frac{2\theta + 1}{2} - y \right)^2 \, dy \\
E((\overline{Y} - Y)^2) &= \int_{\theta}^{\theta+1} \left( \theta + \frac{1}{2} - y \right)^2 \, dy  \\ 
E((\overline{Y} - Y)^2) &= -\frac{ \left( \theta + \frac{1}{2} - y \right)^3}{3} \Big|_{\theta}^{\theta+1} \\
E((\overline{Y} - Y)^2) &= -\frac{ \left( \theta + \frac{1}{2} - \left( \theta+1 \right)  \right)^3}{3} +
 \frac{ \left( \theta + \frac{1}{2} - \theta \right)^3}{3} \\
E((\overline{Y} - Y)^2) &= -\frac{\left( - \frac{1}{2} \right) ^3}{3} + \frac{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right) ^3}{3} \\ 
E((\overline{Y} - Y)^2) &= \frac{ \frac{1}{8} }{3} + \frac{ \frac{1}{8}} {3} \\  
E((\overline{Y} - Y)^2) &= \frac{1}{12} \\
\end{align*}
However, the book gets:
$$ \frac{1}{12n} + \frac{1}{4} $$

Based upon the comments I got from George Dewhirst. I am going to try again.
\begin{align*}
MSE &= E\left( \left( \frac{1}{y_n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} y_i - \frac{2 \theta + 1}{2} \right) ^ 2 \right)
\end{align*}
I am going to look at the special case of $n = 1$.
\begin{align*}
MSE &= E\left( \left( y_1 - \frac{2 \theta + 1}{2} \right) ^ 2 \right) \\
MSE &= \int_{\theta}^{\theta+1} \left( y_1 - \frac{2 \theta + 1}{2} \right) ^ 2 \, dy_1 \\
MSE &= \frac{ \left( y_1 - \frac{2 \theta + 1}{2} \right) ^ 3}{3} \big|_{\theta}^{\theta+1} \\
MSE &= \frac{ \left( \theta + 1 - \frac{2 \theta + 1}{2} \right) ^ 3}{3} - \frac{ \left( \theta - \frac{2 \theta + 1}{2} \right) ^ 3}{3} \\
MSE &= \frac{ \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) ^ 3}{3} - \frac{ \left( \frac{-1}{2} \right) ^ 3 }{3}  = \frac{1}{24} + \frac{1}{24} \\
MSE &= \frac{1}{12}
\end{align*}
For the special case of $n = 1$ the book gets $\frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{4}$ or $\frac{1}{3}$. Hence, I conclude my answer is wrong.

I know have what I believe to be the correct solution. I am hoping that somebody can confirm that it is right or tell me where I went wrong.

Part c:
\begin{align*}
MSE(\overline{Y}) &= V(\overline{Y}) + B^2 \\
\text{Now we need to find the variance of $\overline{Y}$.} \\
\end{align*}
Recall that the variance of a uniformly distributed random variable on the interval $[a,b]$ is $\frac{b-a}{12}$. Hence the variance
of $y_i$ is $\frac{1}{12}$.
\begin{align*}
Var(\overline{Y}) &= \left( \frac{1}{n} \right) \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {\frac{1}{12}} \\
Var(\overline{Y}) &= \frac{1}{12n} \\
MSE( \overline{\theta} ) &= Var( \overline{\theta} ) + B^2 \\
MSE( \overline{\theta} ) &= \frac{1}{12} + \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) ^2 \\
MSE( \overline{\theta} ) &= \frac{1}{12n} + \frac{1}{4} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes it is because $\bar{Y} \neq (2\theta+1)/2$, that is its expected value.

Comment: also isn't MSE = $E[(\bar{Y}-\mu)^2]$ where $\mu = E[\bar{Y}]$

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Now I have: $MSE = E\left( \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} y_i - \theta \right) ^ 2 \right) $. Is that right?

Comment: MSE  = $E[(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i - \frac{2\theta+1}{2})^2]$

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Comments are not for answering questions.  If you would like to provide an answer, use the answer feature instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula for correlation is:
$$\rho = \frac{\sigma_{xy}}{ \sigma_x \sigma_y } $$
Observe that the $E(X) = E(Y) = 0$.
\begin{align*}
E(X^2) &= \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{x^2}{2} \, dx = \frac{x^3}{6} \Big|_{-1}^{1} = \frac{1}{6} - \frac{-1}{6} \\
E(X^2) &= \frac{1}{3} \\
\sigma_x^2 &= E(X^2) - (E(x))^2 = \frac{1}{3} \\
\sigma_x &=\frac{ \sqrt{3} }{3} \\
E(Y^2) &= \int_{-1}^{1} y^2 f(y) \, dy = \int_{-1}^{0} y^2 f(y) \, dy + \int_{0}^{1} y^2 f(y) \, dy \\
E(Y^2) &= 2 \int_{-1}^{1} y^2 f(y) \, dy = \int_{-1}^{0} y^2 f(y) \, dy \\
\int_{-1}^{0} y^2 (y+1) \, dy &= \int_{-1}^{0} y^3 + y^2 \,\, dy = \frac{y^4}{4} + \frac{y^3}{3} \Big|_{-1}^{0} \\
\int_{-1}^{0} y^2 (y+1) \, dy &= 0 - \left( \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{3} \right) \\
\int_{-1}^{0} y^2 (y+1) \, dy &= \frac{1}{12} \\
E(Y^2) &= \frac{1}{6} \\
\sigma_y^2 &= E(Y^2) - (E(y))^2 = \frac{1}{6} \\
\sigma_y &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} = \frac{ \sqrt{6} } {6}
\end{align*}
Now we need to find $\sigma_{xy}$.To do this, we need to find $E(XY)$. Observe that if $-1\leq x \leq 0$ then the area under the $f(x)$
between $x = -1$ and $x = 0$ is $\left( \frac{1}{2}\right) (x + 1)$. Now we need to find $y$ in terms of $x$.
\begin{align*}
\left( \frac{1}{2}\right) (x + 1) &= \int_{-1}^{y} y + 1 \, dy = \frac{y^2}{2} + y \Big|_{-1}^{y} \\
\left( \frac{1}{2}\right) (x + 1) &= \frac{y^2}{2} + y - \left( \frac{1}{2} - 1 \right) \\
\left( \frac{1}{2}\right) (x + 1) &= \frac{y^2}{2} + y + \frac{1}{2} \\
x + 1 &= y^2 + 2y + 1 \\
x &= y^2 + 2y \\
E(XY) &= 2 \int_{-1}^{0} (y^2+y)(y)(y+1) \, dy \\
\int_{-1}^{0} (y^2+y)(y)(y+1) \, dy &= \int_{-1}^{0} y^4 + y^3 + y^3 + y^2 \, dy \\
\int_{-1}^{0} (y^2+y)(y)(y+1) \, dy &= \int_{-1}^{0} y^4 + 2y^3 + y^2 \, dy \\
\int_{-1}^{0} (y^2+y)(y)(y+1) \, dy &=  \frac{y^5}{5}+ \frac{2y^4}{4} + \frac{y^3}{3} \Big|_{-1}^{0} \\
\int_{-1}^{0} (y^2+y)(y)(y+1) \, dy &=0 - \left( -\frac{1}{5} + \frac{2}{4} - \frac{1}{3} \right) = 
\frac{1}{5} - \frac{2}{4} + \frac{1}{3}  \\
\int_{-1}^{0} (y^2+y)(y)(y+1) \, dy &= \frac{1}{30} \\
\end{align*}
%
% Work to do to find E(XY)
%
Now, we want to find a relationship between $X$ and $Y$. We will consider the case where $0 \leq x \leq 1$. The area under both curves
must be the same.
\begin{align*}
\left( \frac{1}{2}\right) \left( x + 1 \right) &= \left( \frac{1}{2}  \right) \left( y + 1 \right) \left( y + 1 \right)  \\
x + 1 &= y^2 + 2y + 1 \\
x &= y^2 + 2y \\
E(XY) &= 2 \int_{-1}^0 xy (y+1) \, dy = 2 \int_{-1}^0 (y^2 + 2y)y (y+1) \, dy \\
\end{align*}
Using an online integral calculator, I find the value of this integral to be $\frac{7}{30}$.
\begin{align*}
E(XY) &= \frac{7}{30} \\
\rho &= \frac{ \left( \frac{7}{30} \right) }{ \left( \frac{ \sqrt{3} }{3}  \right) \left( \frac{ \sqrt{6} } {6} \right)  } =
\frac{ 7(18) } { 30 \sqrt{18} } \\
\rho &= \frac{7(9)}{ 15 \sqrt{18 } } = \frac{7(9)}{ 15 \sqrt{9(2) } } \\
\rho &= \frac{63}{45 \sqrt{2} } \\
\rho &\doteq 0.98994 \\
\end{align*}